# What controls the position and font of the counter in the text related to a footnote?

Tags: formatting

Using amsmath, the counters showing in the text relating to each footnote are not raised, and appear in a font that is different from the normal font.
What controls the position and the type of font used in the text.

Comment: `amsmath` does not do anything with footnotes, do you mean the ams classes such as `amsart` ?

Comment: ams document classes do not change the "default" position and font of footnote markers; they are superscripted.  however, ordinarily, this is *definitely* a function of the document class you are using.

Comment: The following code changes formatting of the actual footnote, but what controls the font and position of the counter in the text?  \makeatletter
    \long\def\@makefntext#1{\parindent 1em\noindent
            \hb@xt@1.8em{%
                \hss\@textsuperscript{\small\@thefnmark}}#1}%
\makeatother

Comment: @keith77777 the footnote mark is by default set by `\def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}` but you haven't clarified  what you mean by the reference to `amsmath`

Comment: David, Sorry, I'm not sure what that means.  I am using amsmath with quite a few added packages. When I apply superscript to say, the number 2, it raises the number quite a bit, whereas the counters are hardly raised at all.

Comment: @keith77777 the footnotes may be using a certain style and you may be using `amsmath` but these are unrelated. the letters `foot` appear nowhere in `amsmath.sty` that package is only concerned with math environments. So you need to show us an example document so we can see what is affecting the footnotes.

Comment: @keith77777: What do you mean by `raise the counters`?

Comment: I think he means that a regular subscript is raised by more than a footnote mark.

Comment: David - I found this piece of code which solved the problem for me:  \renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}} - why it became necessary, I do not know.  Thanks to you all.

Comment: You wrote, " I am using ... quite a few added packages." Clearly, it's not `amsmath` that determines the appearance of the footnote marks. Please tell us which other packages are loaded by your document.

Comment: Dear all - the specific problem has been resolved by adding one line of code (removing that line brings the problem back).  I am not expert in these matters, but I believe the problem is to do with the packages loaded together with quite a bit of other preamble.  If someone would be willing to trawl through the whole preamble with a view to making it more efficient, then I would happily forward a MWE of about 800 lines.